# Парсинг DOCX файла

Tags: php

Всем доброго времени суток. Помогите решить одну задачу. Клиенты загружают файлы(docx) на сервер. Обычно это договоры. Мне нужно парсить эти документы и проверять их тип(типовой или нет договор). Т.е у меня есть шаблон типового договора. Если загруженный файл совпадает с моим шаблоном то это типовой договор. Вопрос: как правильно брать содержимое docx файлов. Я пытался с помощью библиотек(PHP) дергать plain text с файла и записывать в string. Потом парсить этот стринг. Но что-то не выходит совсем. Шаблон храниться в базе в виде предложении. Т.е я проверяю если есть эти предложения в файле то значит это типовой договор.

Comment: docx - зазипованный xml. То есть сперва его нужно unzip (распаковать), потом можно использовать xml-парсер. Но лучше использовать специальную библиотеку для работы с docx.

Comment: phpword попробуйте использовать